# Interop assembly not found in F# solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#

F# newbie here, spent many painful hours trying to resolve the errors with a simple piece of code from MSDN F# tutorial.

```
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" 
// fails with invalid/not found errors

#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" // works like a charm.
```

Any F# gurus know why?

Comment: I would guess that it isn't found in the first case because you haven't supplied a path to the dll. The second case probably succeeds because the assembly is registered in the gac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll"` is the name of a **file** (inferred, because of the `.dll` suffix). When you supply a file name, `#r` will look for that file in the file system. Since you didn't supply a path, it'll look in your present working directory. Most likely, `"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll"` isn't in your working directory. This explains why the first example fails.

`"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"`, on the other hand, is inferred to be the name of an **assembly** (because there's no file extension). Assemblies are libraries, and are normally distributed in `.dll` files. They don't have to, though; they can, for example, be dynamically emitted at run-time. Additionally, a `.dll` file can technically contain more than a single assembly, although I've never seen this in the wild. The most normal case is that a `.dll` file contains a single assembly, and that the name of the file corresponds to the name of the assembly.

When you request to load an assembly, the .NET assembly loader (called *Fusion*) starts [looking for an assembly with the requested identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf). It'll start looking in the [Global Assembly Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz), and my guess is that it finds the `"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"` assembly there. This explains why the second example succeeds.